# How to obtain used byte[] from ByteBuffer

Tags: java, bytebuffer

The `java.nio.ByteBuffer` class has a `ByteBuffer.array()` method, however this returns an array that is the size of the buffer's capacity, and not the used capacity. Due to this, I'm having quite a bit of issues.

I've noticed that using `ByteBuffer.remaining()` gives me the amount of bytes that are currently being used by the buffer, so basically what I'm looking for is a way to get a `byte[]` of ONLY the bytes being used. (ie, the bytes that are being displayed in `ByteBuffer.remaining()`.

I've tried a few different things, but I seem to be failing, the only workaround I can think of it to create another `ByteBuffer` with the allocated size of the remaining buffer, then write (x) bytes to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From reading the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html), I think remaining only gives you number of bytes between current position and limit.

> remaining()
>
> Returns the number of elements between the current position and the limit.

Furthermore:

> A buffer's capacity is the number of elements it contains. The capacity of a buffer is never negative and never changes.
>
> A buffer's limit is the index of the first element that should not be read or written. A buffer's limit is never negative and is never greater than its capacity.
>
> A buffer's position is the index of the next element to be read or written. A buffer's position is never negative and is never greater than its limit.

So with all that in mind how about this:

```
static byte[] getByteArray(ByteBuffer bb) {
    byte[] ba = new byte[bb.limit()];
    bb.get(ba);
    return ba;
}
```

This uses ByteBuffer's `get(byte[] dst)` method

> public ByteBuffer get(byte[] dst)
>
> Relative bulk get method.
>   This method transfers bytes from this buffer into the given destination array. An invocation of this method of the form src.get(a) behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation
>
> ```
>  src.get(a, 0, a.length)
> ```

Comment: This has a bug, you have to bb.rewind(); before the bb.get(ba); statement, otherwise this will throw BufferUnderflowException. 
i.e. If there are fewer bytes remaining in the buffer than are required to satisfy the request, that is, if length > remaining(), then no bytes are transferred and a BufferUnderflowException is thrown

Answer (score 0):

Allocate a `byte[]` if necessary, and then use the `ByteBuffer.get(byte[])` or `ByteBuffer.get(byte[], int, int)` method to copy bytes into the array.  Depending on the state of the `ByteBuffer` you may need to `flip` it first.

In some cases it may also be possible to get the backing array for the `ByteBuffer`, but this is *not recommended* ...

For more details, the javadocs are [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html).